# Liquibase installation <PATH> in is not a valid Liquibase install

Tags: jenkins, liquibase, agent

i am trying to run liquibase runner using jenkins, when i run it in jenkins master it works great using automatic install, but when i try to run it in a jenkisn agent it shows this error:

````
Liquibase home: /home/jenkins/agent/tools/org.jenkinsci.plugins.liquibase.install.LiquibaseInstallation/Liquibase
FATAL: Liquibase installation /home/jenkins/agent/tools/org.jenkinsci.plugins.liquibase.install.LiquibaseInstallation/Liquibase is not a valid Liquibase install
Build step 'Liquibase: Update Database' changed build result to NOT_BUILT ```

this is my configuration in the Global Tools Configurations:

[enter image description here][1]

this is my configuration in the freestyle job:

[enter image description here][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nt9n.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSoYc.png
````

Comment: this is my configuration in the Global Tools Configurations:

 https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nt9n.png

this is my configuration in the freestyle job:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSoYc.png

Comment: the version that i am using of liquibase runner plugin for jenkins is 1.4.10

Comment: https://github.com/jenkinsci/liquibase-runner-plugin/releases

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the same problem by changing the version of liquibase. The FATAL error was obtained by using a version later than 4.13.0 from the Liquibase community version, which I see is the last one supported by the Jenkins plugin.